# Error al tipar props con una interface Vue3 + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue3, composition-api

Errores al tipar los props usando una interface, este es mi código y funciona correctamente.
Pero:

```
defineProps<Props>();
```

Se resalta el siguiente error (Vue: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Client } from "@/clients/interfaces/client.interface";

interface Props {
  clients: Client[];
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

Leyendo y buscando encontré en la mayoría de los sitios que configurando el .eslintrc con

```
  env: {
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true
  }
```

en otro sitio que había que instalar la siguiente dependencia de desarrollo:
"@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0"

Uso webStorm para desarrollar aunque he probado con visual studio code y recibo errores similares.
Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Cuando creaste el proyecto instalaste eslint para Vue 3?

Comment: Buenas, René.
Si instalé eslint en el proyecto.

Comment: Que pasa si defines el tipo de dato dentro al usar `defineProps`? O si usas `withDefaults`?

Comment: La cosa era que la documentación explica esta forma que expongo en el fallo y me causaba estres el no saber porque daba el error, pero gracias a tu comentario caí en el eslint, es algo en lo que no pienso de serie porque lo utilizo en el día a día, pero con typescript parece ser bastante exquisito. Puse una respuesta con la solución que implemente, valida como muchas otras pero es la que más me gustaba.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html la sintaxis utilizaza en la descripción del problema es correcta (mirar documentación) pero no le gusta a eslint como bien comenta René.
Solución que implementé:
Una de las otras opciones de la documentación, ej. de código:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Book {
  title: string
  author: string
  year: number
}

const props = defineProps<{
  book: Book
}>()
</script>
```

De esta manera no recibo el error de eslint, puedo declarar el tipo de prop con la interface correspondiente y sin lo verboso de declarar cada prop con su type y require, etc.